# How can i configure apache2 to be an HLS server with ffserver

Tags: server, apache2, ffmpeg

I want to setup ffmpeg and ffserver on my ubuntu 16.04, whereby client can access the video via hls streaming. Please i am a novice, can somebody help me out please, i need a detail from start to finish. I have already installed LAMP server and ffmpeg which has ffserver in it.

Comment: This is my actual task. "You would need to install FFMPEG streaming server on your linux laptop and set up to stream videos. You would need to configure the HLS streaming over http link, it means that your laptop will be connected to the wifi router and a client will also connect to the same router and the HLS server will be on your laptop and via an http link the client should be able to view the video using his laptop or phone etc."

Comment: "Remember HLS streaming will require you to setup apache web server plus you would need to transcode the mp4 vidoe into hls streaming and then copy it to the apache and can be playing in any player that can play hls streaming videos."